# How to change CSS file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, src

I would ask how to change src of CSS using pure Javascript. I saw on internet that one guy used cookies for this, by i tried sth like this:

```
window.onload = function onload() {
setTimeout(function(){
    document.styleSheets[1].href = "file:///C:/Users/Ma%C5%9Blan/Desktop/Site/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/project1a.css";
    }, 3000);
```

};

And it didn't work (i want to change CSS after 3 s, i know that actual localization is local, on my PC. Just trying :) ). I want to swap whole file.

Any ideas? If it's impossible in pure JS, show me jQuery way then.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you change a css file ? Then you would need to re-load (// re-render) the page to update the changes.. Use the Javascript attribute handler.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style or maybe you are looking to specify a css file, in which case you will need to inject it before document ready.. More description to what you want to achieve would be great.

Comment: I am using a lot of CSS for whole document. After 3 s i need to change a lot of elements so I wanted to change whole CSS, it would be easier for me :/

Comment: I want to swap CSS file.

Comment: I would remove the css file and recreate it with the new source - to make sure the new styles render.

Comment: How? I've got no idea.

Comment: Meant to say style tag above ^^ Select the parent, and delete the child (Vanilla JS)
if you want to use jquery you can simply use `$(stylesheet).remove()`

now

`document.head += (style = document.createElement("style"));`
-JQ `$("head").append(style = document.createElement("style"))`

finally

style.src="src"

Comment: If you want some extra information, you can read it at W3C with explanation. https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

`document.styleSheets` is a READ-ONLY property, so you won't be able to change the properties of that array.

What you want to do instead is get a list of all the `<link>` elements in the head, then either use a regex or conditional statement to get the element you are looking to replace, and use `.href` on that element.

E.G.

```
// get all links in the head (including CSS)
var allLinks = document.head.getElementsByTagName('link');
// find and replace the element
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
    if ( allLinks[i].href = "old/url/to/css/file.css") {
        allLinks[i].href = "file:///C:/Users/Ma%C5%9Blan/Desktop/Site/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/project1a.css";
    }
}
```